# Is it possible to submit a new testflight version while another version is in the review queue?

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight, beta-testing

An app I'm working on has version 1.0.1 in waiting for review. We submitted a build of version 1.0.2 using application loader with the intent of making it available as a prerelease build for testers while 1.0.1 is in the queue. An hour or two later we received an email saying that version 1.0.1 had been developer rejected.

Is there some way to have a version in the review queue, while our testers test the next version as a prerelease build via testflight beta distribution?

Comment: So how did you scenario go? Can you update your experience?

Comment: For 2018 - yes, there's absolutely no problem with this.  If it's literally the "first" one (getting the "quasi human slow review") it will of course *probably* bump that one out.  (The details of the process change slightly from time to time, so it depends when you're reading this.)  If it is "just another build number", it's no problem, it won't bump or change anything. Here's an exhaustive description of the process BTW ! https://stackoverflow.com/a/38396347/5638630

Answer (score 3):

This is possible. You can upload new builds of, say, 1.0.2 to iTunes Connect and test them via TestFlight while version 1.0.1 is "waiting for review".

I did that with my app. I uploaded all the builds with Xcode, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Bad if you are "In Review". I tried this exact procedure while one of our builds was "In Review" (beta review), and the upload "killed" the "In Review" of the old build and we went back to "Waiting for Review" on the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can only thing you have to ensure is your build version should be differnt.