# iOS app submission and beta review process

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm currently developing an iOS application for a client. The submission review process to the store can often be a lengthy process and is relatively new to me.

My client wants to do a beta test using **TestFlight** as well as submitting the app to the app store afterwards, through **XCode** and **Itunes Connect**.

Scouring Apple's documentation I can't seem to get a good idea of following:

- **If I want to update an existing application on the store do I have to go through the review process again in full?**
- **If I have my app approved for beta testing release through TestFlight, is this taken into consideration when submitting the app for review to the store?**
- **If I want to test a new build through TestFlight, do I need to go through the beta review process again in full?**
- **If an app is approved on the app store, does it automatically pass the beta review?**
   
  (This sounds counterintuitive considering you don't want to do a beta test after releasing to the store but in a scenario where you may want to do a closed release of an update for testing while a live version is up on the store)

Comment: Yes All will go with the review process. but update might be little bit quicker.

Comment: if you are short on time you can go for Expedited App Review.

Comment: Interesting! I will look into that. Are Expedited App reviews only for apps on the app store or do they include apps that are set for beta release?

Comment: Only for the appstore.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

## Useful preliminary tip!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55044137/294884

## Critical! news for 2019

As of February, there's a bug on the new iTunes connect. (Who would have thought?)

If your test flight build is stuck on "processing" (after, say, 5 minutes)...

In fact, simply **log out of appstoreconnect.apple.com and log back in**.

Amazingly, it will now be ...

[image]

This seems to work "often", perhaps even "all the time", if it's stuck for more than 5 mins.

I would say this problem happens about 3 times in ten.

Another point that is harder to demonstrate. Traditionally if a build was "stuck": if you increased the build number by one and just archived and sent it again. That seemed to flush forward the first one that was stuck. Unfortunately the "add one" trick seems to not work any more. If a build is "stuck" it seems to just stay "stuck".

---

## News for 2018 !

Changes for 2018!

1. Apple had the famous "utter disaster" of the end of 2017 / early 2018 where (basically) nothing worked for some weeks.  It seems to have generally settled down as of Feb 2018.
2. Change!  Regarding the delay: "for betas (nothing to do with the app store), the delay you must experience, each time you have a new *version number* of your beta."  That was usually quite short ("about one day"); now it is distinctly longer ("about two days").  They changed something.

(Note - don't forget that: also when you actually send a version to the App Store, that "forces" you to now have a new version number on the betas.  So, if it's Monday morning and your launch team gets a new version approved (for the app store), and then it's Monday afternoon and you're about to send out a new beta build, in fact you now *have to* go up a version (and you will get the delay mentioned in the previous point).)

3. Change!  Regarding the delay: "for betas (nothing to do with the app store), the delay you must experience, each time you simply upload a new build (so, a higher build number) with no change to the version number."  Basically this is now **longer, but nor broken.** It used to be that this usually happened almost instantly, and, sometimes it would take awhile (say 5-10 minutes), and finally sometimes it was completely broken (as described below).  **For 2018:** they have changed it. It now always takes "5-10 minutes".  (It never happens instantly.)  And they do seem to have **resolved the problem** where it is sometimes broken and you have to try again: that seems to be history, fortunately.
4. Change!  Submissions to the actual app store.  Simply, these are quicker now, in general.  (Even if you have in app purchase - whatever.) Perhaps they improved their handling for testors, automated something, or whatever.

## For mid 2016 (updated for 2018) ...

> If I want to update an existing application on the store do I have to go through the review process again in full?

yes, definitely.

> If I have my app approved for beta testing release through TestFlight, is this taken into consideration when submitting the app for review to the store?

No, for better or worse it is **absolutely unrelated**.

(Indeed: it's fairly common to submit straght to the store. To be clear, many companies simply never use TestFlight in any way. You don't have to if you don't want to.)

> If I want to test a new build through TestFlight, do I need to go through the beta review process again in full?

Say you have an app HappyApp:

The **first** time you submit it for **beta** testing, there is a delay: **usually of about two days**.

That is while waiting for "beta approval". So that's "build 1" of your **beta** version of HappyApp on TestFlight.

## Every FIRST *TestFlight* build, has - for sure - a delay of about two days:

(Note - this has changed in early 2018 from "about one day" to "about two days".)

This appears to be a human process. (Nobody knows for sure.) You can rely on this delay, it is never shorter. This is exactly what a beta looks like during that one-day delay:

> [image]

So you have to wait about two days for the *first* review of a given beta *version number*.

On to the next step. So, for builds 2, 3, 4, 5 .. of HappyApp *on TestFlight*:

When you submit each new build, there is **a delay of 5-10 minutes** for each of those new builds to go through.

## All beta builds after the first, have a 5-10 minute delay.

- as of early 2018, that delay is reliably 5-10 minutes
- in the old days, sometimes it happened instantly: **this is no longer the case**. It is now always 5-10 minutes
- in the old days, often it would "just break" at this stage.  *They do appear to have finally fixed this problem, after three years of developers complaining.* There was a large section in this post dealing with the issue, any history buffs can find it in the edits!

> If an app is approved on the app store, does it automatically pass the beta review?

Stupidly, no.  You have to **completely start again**.

So TBC.  Say you're on **version 4** of your app.  You're going along making beta builds every few hours for your team.  Build number 3010, 3011, 3012, etc. As it happens, you submit a real build to the app store and get the next version of the app approved - so that will be **version 5** in the app store.  Simply then - on the beta side - you are then **forced** to change to a new version number.  (And thus as it explains above, you then will the suffer the "two day delay" on the next beta you send in, because, it is indeed the first beta of a new version number.)

A commentor wrote...

> (All of this sounds counterintuitive...

Everything about Apple's approval process is silly. Leave your common sense at the door!  :/

Updated for Feb 2018 !

---

Footnote! Apple previously had an annoying problem where: with a brand-new app (brand new BundleID, etc) it would take about half an hour to simply appear in your list of apps on iTunesConnect. This was quite confusing. Fortunately this problem is now history.

Comment: I would give you 200 upvotes if I could. This is a very informative answer and will be of benefit to myself and anyone wanting to upload to the App store. Thank you very much for taking the time to write this!

Comment: absolutely no problem, I just hope it helps someone!  Thanks!!  My most recent "first Beta" (know what I mean?) went through yesterday, in fact it took from Thursday 7PM until Friday 4PM, so that's a good example.

Comment: hey @JoeBlow I went ahead and created a request for a topic under the iOS Tag on documentation called [App Submission Process](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/topic-requests/23116). I thought that this answer and answers like it could serve as a basis for that topic~ Just thought I'd let you know incase you or others who come across this question want to contribute~

Comment: Really helpful.  I've been flailing, clicking and refreshing and trying to figure out why my upload/app addition/etc. "didn't work" and it's just b/c these changes take an unpredictable amount of time to propagate, as you note.  We're 1/2 way through the process, thanks for helping us know what to expect!

Comment: @Fattie Thanks for this post. I'm not sure what's going on, this is what the status of my app looks like under the Testflight tab in itunesconnect - http://imgur.com/lsAITOO . The 2 itunesconnect users are able to download the app, but the other 4 people invited didn't get any invitations. Additionally, how do I know if the App is even in Beta Review?  The attached image seems to indicate that the app should be available to everyone, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Fattie big thanks for taking your time to write this long informative answer.

Comment: My first beta build (0.9.1) was approved after one day, but my second beta build (0.9.2) for external testers is again "Waiting for Review" for half a day already. Is this a common scenario, and solved by submitting an incremented build again?

Comment: Hi @marcovtwout **YES, THE PROBLEM IS YOU CHANGED THE VERSION NUMBER!!**  For your convenience, never change the version number: just change the build number!  Literally the only reason to change the version number is if, for some reason, you want it to be beta-approved by Apple!

Comment: @Fattie If I already rolled out a certain build/version to external testers, do they still get the new release if I submit a new build (number) but with the same version number?

Comment: that's totally correct @marcovtwout.  Always change only the build number.  There is, really, never a reason to change the version number.

Comment: New data point from August 2018: Beta review of new version number took 17 hours in the middle of the week, a following new build number was released without any delay

Comment: Does beta review still take two days? I have an emergency fix I am trying to test with a user and it is imperative that this fix actually be tested with her (and hopefully then submitted for actual review) ASAP.

Comment: hi @SAHM - yes.  If you have an "emergency" *and you're a large company* (so, it's the app of a bank) you would already have a personal contact at Apple, and they deal with things like that.  If it's just "you or me", it won't happen any quicker.  Sorry!

Comment: @Fattie The testflight build statuses don't seem to match the documentation. Mine shows In Review rather than In Beta Review. Does that mean I'm in Beta Review and still waiting on apple to approve? [App Build Statuses](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev3d6869aff)

Comment: yeah, the doco is rubbish  :)  @vdidxho - I'm not sure quite what stage you're at; the  "first" time you send one in on TestFlight there's a long review (1-2 days), and subsequent increases in build number have only  few hrs review.

Answer (score 25):

I feel that this thread is lacking a clear and concise answer to your questions.

In order of questions asked:

1. **Yes**- if you want to update an existing app in the App Store, **you must go through the review process again.**
2. **No**- If your app is approved in the Beta review process, this is **not** taken into account for the official review process.  You will still need to wait the normal duration for official review.
3. **It depends*** If you want to test a new build with TestFlight, you will have to wait for the beta review process again **if you changed the version number**.  If you changed the build number, it is usually approved instantly.
4. **No**, if a version is approved for the app store, it is not auto-approved for TestFlight.  MORE IMPORTANTLY- once you have a version approved for the official App Store, **you CANNOT push a new build to your TestFlight users with the same *version number* as the pre-approved official App Store app**.  You must change the version number if you want to push a new build to your TestFlight users, AND it will be subjected to a longer beta app review process because it is seen as a new 'version'.  The better solution is to remove your pre-approved official app, push a new build to your test flight users, and re-submit your official app for review again.  I know it's stupid, but it's the only effective solution.

Comment: Tbh I think there needs to be a Documentation topic on SO for app-store related questions like this. Too bad as of now there isn't enough users committed to start one.

Comment: @Danoram that's an excellent idea.  I would love it if that existed!  It would help out so many people!  What can we do to create one?

Comment: Glad to see the enthusiasm! I just went ahead and created a topic under the iOS tag on Documentation, just to get the ball rolling - [App Submission Process](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/topic-requests/23116)

Comment: Thanks for highlighting nr. 3

Answer (score 14):

**Update July 2019**

**TestFlight review times:**

- **First upload build**: takes 36h average.
- **Updates**: take from 6h to 20h average for Build.

Weekends are off.

More information here:

[IOS APP SUBMISSION AND BETA REVIEW PROCESS TIMES](http://www.jazzcoding.com/ios-app-submission-and-beta-review-process/)

Comment: Is it common that updates are this slow to process? Earlier information indicated TestFlight updates to be approved immediately or within 15 minutes.

Comment: @ marcovtwout This is based on my experience and I manage several Apps across many Stores accounts.

Comment: I can corroborate these times -- for months it's been a day and a half for the first upload and about a full business day (e.g. submit Friday night, won't be approved until Monday morning) for updates.

Answer (score 4):

The review process is really quick for both the Beta and Final build. I found that the Final build review process was even quicker once I put it through the Beta.

You'll have to get all releases checked but that's because you have to submit a review for each build you intend on pushing to the store. This is to make sure nobody gets an app up and then tries to sneak in another app that's completely different (and possibly malicious).

For new TestFlight builds you have to submit it for review again but Apple is really quick with approving them. And once it's approved it'll send you an email saying it was approved and it'll automatically send everyone a notification, through Testflight, that the new build is available for update

Once the App is approved the App Store then everyone who was on the Beta update will be able to update to the latest build that's currently available on the App Store.

The Beta builds and the Final builds may be exactly the same but Apple treats them differently so you can't get it approved for the App Store but then start using TestFlight with that build that was just approved. The App Store is the App Store and Testflight is TestFlight.

Comment: To chime in here, I've submitted many apps directly to the store, but last week I submitted my first app to TestFlight review.  I have a hard time believing they do much of a "review" or if it's even a real person.  The first build I submitted (it was approved) crashed immediately upon tapping the start button.  I only found out when a tester told me about it.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup surprisingly I have had them rejected in the beta review for TFA!  One time, I clicked one up without thinking about it much as a "stub", it had some database code or whatever that didn't connect They rejected it!  On the other hand often I just send a completely blank app (ie white, does nothing!) and that passes!!!!  Since that is the only review (just change the build number from there) you can then do whatever you want, heh!