# Testflight while app is "waiting for review"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

We are in a hurry to publish an app for a customer, so yesterday we published an app to App Store and now is "Waiting for review".

Meanwhile, the customer aked if he could have a preview. My idea was to send him a TestFlight beta testing. I'm thinking in several options:

- Start an internal testflight for the build that is in review for team customer users
- Start an external testflight with the build is in review for other customer users not in the team
- Send a new build and start internal testflight for team customer users
- Send a new build and start external testflight for other customer users not in the team

What I'm not sure is on each case (internal/external testflight):

- Can I start a testflight testing for a build that is "in review"? And if I can, will it cancel the "in review" process for this build?
- Can I send another build while there is already one "in review"? And if I can, will it cancel the "in review" process for the previous build? If it will not, can I start a testflight for a new build while previous one is in review?

As said, the priority here is not to stop the "in review" process.

**EDIT**

I've been reading docs at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html and what makes me be scared is:

> When you are done using TestFlight beta testing, you can submit the app for final review

So it seems that testflight is more like an step in the process than a parallel option in the process...

Comment: full up to date details!  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38396347/294884

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From answer at below link:

[Will submitting a build for TestFlight Beta Testing stop the Final Review Test for the same build?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28421981/5575752)

> Apple will review as normal even with an active TestFlight and
> external testers using it.

What apple doc at below link says:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html

> When you are done using TestFlight beta testing, you can submit the
> app for final review. Before you submit it, make sure you no longer
> want to test it or any builds you uploaded earlier than it. When the
> app becomes Ready for Sale in the App Store, testing automatically
> stops on earlier builds, and you will be unable to view or test them.
>
> If you want to resume testing of an earlier build, you can upload it
> as a new build associated with a new prerelease version.

So, when the app becomes ***Ready for Sale*** in the App Store, testing automatically stops on this and earlier builds, and you will be unable to view or test them.

Comment: Yeah, I was reading apple docs and what made me be scared is *"When you are done using TestFlight beta testing, you can submit the app for final review"*, it seems more like a process than an option

Comment: **Ready for Sale** is status after that you will not be able to test it@Miquel

Comment: Yeah...while app is in review or in submission looks like horror movie running, no one know what will happen..hahaha@Miquel

Answer (score 34):

Would be nice to have had a reply after your "will give a try..."

So I had the same issues a few minutes ago:

- App is "waiting for review".
- And no internal/external testing available for the client.

Since the external testing will also need a review by Apple I went for the internal way. So I added my and the clients account to internal testing. Then I added the current build which is also in "waiting for review" state to the internal testing.

Result: It worked. I got the invite email and could download that build via TestFlight. The app is still "waiting for review".

Just in case someone else stumbles upon this question/answer here.

Comment: this should be the answer!  internal testing.  but where did you set internal testing?

Comment: @pashute : I was facing same issue. I applied above scenario. I didn't even find Internal testing thing. Basically, first you need to create a  internal user "Click on App store Connect : user and Roles ". User will get the invitation email and he has to activate his account. Once account is activate, you need to add same account "App Store Connect Users" list. After that, you will be able to send App testflight link.

Comment: I found it:  
AppStoreConnect.apple.com website -> Apps 
chose: myApp
testflight tab,

Answer (score 4):

You can invite users to test even when the app is in review. It will not be available only when its in store.

For external testing you need the app to be reviewed by Apple just as you publish to store but for internal testing its not required.

1. Send invitation to the user
2. Select your app
3. Go to TestFlight
4. Select Internal Testing
5. Click select version to test on right hand side of the screen
6. Select the users to send test invite
7. Click save

App invite will be sent to all selected users.

Comment: but i cannot invite myself anywhere.

Comment: I found it:  
AppStoreConnect.apple.com website -> Apps 
chose: myApp, ->
testflight tab,  -> testers -> add group and add yourself to group (you already are an internal tester). On the left sidebar click ios and choose the version you want to test. groups add group to this test. and you'll get an invite as part of the group.

Answer (score 1):

You always have the option to build an adhoc distribution version of your app. With this anyone who has given you there udid and it has been added to the adhoc provisioning file can install via a link or by using an .IPA file.

The major benefit of this is that the there is no review process. You build and distribute.

[https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/DistributinganApp/DistributinganApp.html#:~:text=the%20App%20Store.-,Ad%20Hoc%20Distribution%20Authorizes%20a%20Limited%20Set%20of%20Devices%20to,devices%20for%20testing%20purposes%20only.&text=You%20distribute%20your%20app%20by,to%20install%20on%20their%20devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/DistributinganApp/DistributinganApp.html#:%7E:text=the%20App%20Store.-,Ad%20Hoc%20Distribution%20Authorizes%20a%20Limited%20Set%20of%20Devices%20to,devices%20for%20testing%20purposes%20only.&text=You%20distribute%20your%20app%20by,to%20install%20on%20their%20devices)

Answer (score 0):

As a first time apple developer publisher - I found the process rather easy than intimidating. I just had preconceived thoughts on the complexities that I would face if comparing to Google.Console publish.

What [railon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5028033/railon) said is still true if not slightly improved since 2017 and should be accepted as an answer.