# Submit iOS build update without re-uploading screen-shots and app-previews

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I want to submit an update for my iOS app, but this seems to require submitting a new version which entails re-entering all information, screenshots, videos, etc.

I can't find anything that explicitly says one can submit solely a new build for an existing version that has already been approved. Is this possible?

If not, is there a way to copy over all of the previous version's information, screenshots, videos, etc. within iTunesConnect?

EDIT:
Specifically, the problem is that screen-shots and app-previews from the previous approved version do not show up by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS app submission and beta review process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004875/ios-app-submission-and-beta-review-process)

Comment: In particular read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39837414/499581

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no need to upload screenshots, videos and other information again and again when you are publishing a new version. Unless you have a new functionality which you want to be presented in the screenshots or you have to support a new apple device.  For example your previous version didn’t support iPhone X, then when you create a new version, there won’t be any screenshot for iPhone X. So you need to upload screenshots only for that specific device.
So, just create the New version and upload the new build and add - What's new in this version. You are then good to go.
As to your question on **whether it is possible to upload a new build to existing live version**. Answer to that is - **NO**. Once an app is live, you always have to create a new version on iTunesConnect and upload build configured with that version number.
As an example, here are two images :

**1. Already existing app on iTunesConnect (live version)**

[image]

**2. New version created. Screenshots already there by default.**

[image]

Comment: When I create a new version (like your example), the only thing already there by default are the name and description. Everything else is empty and my only option seems to be re-uploading everything.

Comment: It might be possible that for screenshot, you are checking iPhone 5.8 size and you might not have screenshots in the previous version. Check for screenshots on that device for which they were set in previous version. (for reference check my screenshot number 2)

Comment: And if you see General app information section and App review information section by scrolling to bottom, even those are pre filled.

Comment: You're correct, switching from 5.8 to 5.5 screen size was the key as I submitted v1 before iPhone X and didn't see the option. I edited my question so if you add that to your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Edited my answer :)

Answer (score 37):

For anyone googling here:

[image]

The problem is this:

It annoyingly ***defaults to (say) 6.5 !!!***

(Whatever is current as you are reading this.)

And it's likely you have no images for that size!!

## Simply click on the other sizes to see your existing images!

That's all it is.

---

## 2019 note ..

As @phihag mentions below, they're always changing "just which one is actually required," but in all events you can click around away from the default to see what's happening.  You may then come to realize that Apple now requires image sizes that are NOT in your previous release, and so you now need to generate a new set of images.

Comment: This was my problem.

Comment: Right.  Nitish explained it.  I just put it here clearly for other googlers!

Comment: It annoyingly defaults to 6.5 now. This was also my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Note you seem to _need_ 6.5" screenshots now. A red error mark appears if none are present.

Comment: @Fattie, It seems as if your answer needs updating.  The answer is "you can click around and see your previous images, but there's no way to get those older device images to the later device (ie from 5.5 to 6.5)", so you need to supply a NEW SET of images.