# Update new iOS Application version to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode

How to update my app in app-store to a newer version?

Earlier, I successfully offered my app into the app-store.  That's the starting point.  But it's been a while, I've updated my app, and would like to offer a new release.  Since a misstep in preparing the app can take a bit of time, I'd like to have the specific steps required to offer an updated release on the Apple app store.

Comment: I'd like an answer with pictures.  I don't do this enough to have the details memorized.

Comment: @Dale it’s not your question

Comment: @matt, Correct, but if I asked the same question but asked for more detail, it would be closed as a duplicate.  So what's a mother to do?

Comment: @Dale You could start a bounty.

Answer (score 9):

## Summary

The process of releasing a new version of an iPhone app to the Apple app store requires quite a number of steps, but not all the steps will be required, depending on whether certificates are up to date, builds are targeting required versions, if you have screen shots for the required devices, etc.  Below is an example of the steps you might need to execute to put a new version into the Apple app store.

## Steps

### 1. Versioning and Signing

Within the XCode application, update the version of your application.  Also check to see that there is a valid provisioning profile.  In this example, the profile is expired, so additional steps will be required.  If you have a valid profile, skip the (lengthy) step 2.

[image: versioning and signing in xcode]

### 2. Updating Provisioning Profile

Skip this step if you have a valid profile.

This process does not use the `Automatically manage signing` feature of the XCode application.  Automatic signing only works if you have a physical, registered Apple device, which I do not have.  So automatic signing might be easier, but is not used here in this example.

#### 2a. Add signing certification

Here we see there are no valid signing certificates, so one is created and associated with the apple ID.

[image: adding ios distribution cert to the apple id]

#### 2b. Manage certificates using `developer.apple.com`

By using the Apple developer web site, we see that an old provisioning profile is expired and we also see our new distribution cert is available.  We create a new distribution profile for the app store and generate a new provisioning profile, then download it.

[image: log on to developer web site and create new signing artifacts]
[image: continue managing artifacts then download the result]

#### 2c. Import the new Provisioning Profile into XCode

After the creation of the new Provisioning profile on the Apple developer web site, we import the new profile into XCode.  If there is a problem with no signing certificate, you might need to select (project) -- > Build Settings and searh for PROVISIONING_PROFILE and tweak that.  Or turn on, then off automatically manage signing.

[image: import provisioning profile into xcode]

### 3. Build and Upload the Application

Here we build the application using a generic device, archive, and upload using the provisioning profile from step 2, or an earlier valid provisioning profile.

We also must wait for the automated processing to complete.  An email is generated and sent by Apple.

[image: building and uploading the application]
[image: status of processing and processing complete email]

### 4. Prepare Application Submission

This is where we assign a `Store Version` number, assign the build file we uploaded in step 3, and reaffirm the application meta data.

The meta data includes screen shots of the application, and Apple requires that certain screen dimensions are represented.  This answer will not explore the challenges associated with the case where Apple creates an additional burden on the developer by requiring different screen shot resolutions.  Instead, an reference to another post will be included:  [Submit iOS build update without re-uploading screen-shots and app-previews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48733726/submit-ios-build-update-without-re-uploading-screen-shots-and-app-previews/51639766#51639766)
.  My conclusion for screen shots is that you can often request (through Media Manager), that screen shots you've uploaded be used on various other devices, but when new hardware is released, you'll probably need to generate new screen shots manually.

[image: assigning store version and adding meta data]
Once the meta data is complete, the version can be submitted to Apple for approval.  This process requires a real person, I think, and has taken at least over night, if not longer.  This answer will not address the application-specific review process, but even though the new version *didn't change anything significant*, you may be asked to alter things in your submission or even within your app.

Comment: I just used this tutorial again, and it was still accurate.

Comment: I used this tutorial with Xcode 12 and this time got really lost in properly aligning certificates and provisioning profiles.  Finally fumbled through it.  The build didn't show-up right away either, which confused me.  The build should show up without you doing anything on the web site (doesn't appear to be a `+` button any more).

Comment: Great answer! Thanks

Comment: Now it;s just add the new version number, select your test flight build and your done. No need for all the provisioning unless you changed your entitlements. It's really a 1 step process now.

Comment: I just used this answer again, and in step 2b, I didn't have a certificate to select in `Generate A Provisioning Profile`.  So I had to go through the process of creating a certificate signing request.  So that part should be included in this answer, but it's not.

Answer (score 5):

steps:

1. in your project in xcode go to Target -> general

there you see version and build,
if your last version in app store was 1.0, now if you have made minor changes in app, new version might be 1.1 0r 1.0.1 etc, and if major app changes, version changes accordingly, i hope you understand what i am saying here
and for build, add 1 to the last build number which you used to upload app in you developer account, not the one in app store.

2. Now clean app, change your provision profiles and certificates accordingly for app store..
3. now clean build the app, and then archive the app
4. after archive completed, a window appear and from there,

either you can export your ipa and  browse to your ipa file, use application loader to upload app or 
click upload button there in window itself.. and follow steps, this might take some time
    depending upon your app size.. and after app upload success, 10-15
    minute time takes, to show your this uploaded build in your
    developer.apple.com console.

5. open the developer console, go to itunes connect -> my apps -> select this app uploaded from list of app available in list

since there is already aversion of your app in appstore.. click on add version, give the version number and select the build you uploaded earlier

and then fill in necessary details and submit for review.

i might have missed a few steps, but thats the general idea.. you will figure it out.

Comment: is there any changes i will do in XCODE such as code signing identity ?, as i knew only to change the version ...

Comment: well, what i am trying to say here is, in your code signing for release, use the appstore distribution provisioning profile, before you start archiving and this may be just waste of time.. so do check once for sigining identity.

Answer (score 2):

- First you have to update version of your app choose target ---> Version Like from 1.0 to 1.1.
- Choose device it's Generic ios device then clean and build the project.
- Make sure you have a valid Production Certificate and provisioning Profile, installed in your mac.
- Go to --> Product --> Archive --> it's open archive window --> then click validate button or it's check validation, if any error occur you have to resolve it.
- then it ask for Certificate and provisioning Profile - Choose correct one.
- if it success then Upload to app store.
- If all work done successful then build show on app store after  some time.You will get a email.
- So for Submit a new build go to itunes connect by login your apple account and open your app then click (+) button version or plateform
  give the version name that you provide for app version and create it.
- then you can change info for this version like new Updates and screen shot if you want otherwise no need to change anything.
- when build your ipa is connect to your account, In Build section of this version  it show a (+) button. by clicking Then you can select your build and save changes and submit to app store.