# Replace SAP Mobile Services app in App Store with SAP Cloud Platform app

Tags: ios, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-mobile-services

Recently we've managed to create a Fiori Cloud Build in the SAP Cloud Platform Mobile Services for Android and iOS.

Currently our users are using Fiori on their mobile devices with a previously developed native app created with the Kapsel SDK, which has been deployed in the Android as well as the Apple App Store.

What we would like to do is replace the currently running Kapsel native app with the in the SAP Cloud Platform Generated "Cloud Build".

[We've heard that](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12929864/a-couple-of-questions-about-the-sap-cloud-platform.html), to publish the Android app in the App Store, we should simply replace the `.apk` in the store.

What we are wondering is how this works with the iOS version? Can the iOS Cloud Build generated version be uploaded to an Apple Store, replacing the currently published (Kapsel) application? And if so, do certificates etc. need to be modified or updated before we do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update new iOS Application version to App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105613/update-new-ios-application-version-to-app-store)

Comment: I suppose nothing will be different from the above question. The only difference from other iOS apps will be [additional SAP framework](https://help.sap.com/viewer/fc1a59c210d848babfb3f758a6f55cb1/Latest/en-US/772faf726c4343e2b6544bc0969898d7.html) `Frameworks/SAPFoundation.framework/SAPFoundation` included in app fat file