# Do iTunesConnect external testers get updates for *every* uploaded ipa file after Beta Approval?

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight, beta

Pardon all the italic shouting. Just trying to emphasize key points. Please note that the existing post [iOS app submission and beta review process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004875/ios-app-submission-and-beta-review-process) does not answer this question.

The following sequence of events does happen and it's what I expect:

- Create a new *version* (number) of app in iTC
- Archive and upload app to iTC
- *Internal* testers get notified to download with TestFlight
- Submit for Beta Approval (critical for next step)
- Now *all* testers (inside & out) get notified to download

But next:

- Create a new *build* (number) in Xcode
- Archive and upload to iTC
- Only *internal* testers are notified. ⬅︎ **unexpected**

Do I need Beta Approval *every* time I want the external testers notified? I could swear this has not been the case. But of course things may have changed. Or it's just my bad memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need Beta Approval every time I want the external testers notified?

## NO

> I could swear this has not been the case. But of course things may have changed. Or it's just my bad memory.

It's just that:

1) there's a short delay (5-20 minutes) before you can send to external testers

2) from time to time Apple's servers are screwed, and the 5-20 minute delay becomes "many hours".

Change the version number - you have to wait for a (presumably human) approval: takes 1-2 days

Change the build number - only a short delay for a (presumably) automatic check.

## And don't forget you have to manually release to the external testers each time!

[image]

Comment: It took a lot of mucking around (i.e. creating dummy projects, dummy versions, dummy build #s) for me to figure out what you so clearly stated. (Sometimes I'm the dummy! :)

Comment: it's the most complicated thing in the universe!  this is why there are build-submit specialists in big teams!  thanks for the tick!

Answer (score -1):

You need to approve first build of every new version.As Apple mentioned" A review is only required for the first build of a version. Subsequent builds may not need a full review.."https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev3bfa33892

Comment: This does not answer my question about whether external testers get notified for subsequent builds.

Answer (score -1):

Beta review is only required for the first build and the first build send in after a 90 day period.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I'm uploading build after build (after Beta Review) and only my internal testers are getting notified. The external ones hear nothing, and when they launch TestFlight, the are offered the opportunity to test *only* the Beta-Approved versions, not any subsequent ones. This is really messing up our test procedure.

Comment: @AndrewDuncan - you have to MANUALLY release it to the external testers each time!  that's the secret to what you're asking I believe